# Deploy a Django site and a PHP site on the same server with Apache and mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I currently have a Django site working at **cinepass.com.ec** , I would like to deploy an additional PHP site to the same server at **mobile.cinepass.com.ec**

My current **httpd.conf** (from [DjangoFoo](http://www.djangofoo.com/17/django-mod_wsgi-deploy-exampl)) :

```
<Directory "/home/ec2-user/cinepass/media">
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/home/ec2-user/cinepass/cinepass">
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /media/ /home/ec2-user/cinepass/media/
ServerAdmin smansfield@palapa.com.ec
ErrorLog "logs/cinepass.com-error_log"
CustomLog "logs/cinepass.com-access_log" common

# mod_wsgi configuration is here
# we are running as user/group 'deamon', if you don't have those you need to change or create.
WSGIDaemonProcess cinepass python-path=/home/ec2-user/cinepass:/home/ec2-user/cinepass/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages user=daemon group=daemon processes=2 threads=25
WSGIProcessGroup cinepass
# this is our WSGI file.
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ec2-user/cinepass/cinepass/wsgi.py
```

My current **wsgi.py** :

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/home/')
sys.path.append('/home/ec2-user/cinepass/')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "cinepass.settings_production.py")
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/tmp'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

How would I edit my Apache configuration so that I can also run a php site at **mobile.cinepass.com.ec**?

Comment: This question may do ok here, but would be better on serverfault

Comment: Gotcha @JeffS, thanks for the tip, if I don't get a response I will post it there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [apache´s virtualhosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/), here I put an example of something similar in a server of mine, in which I have a djangp app in the main domain and a joomla in a subdomain. Both files are located in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`

Joomla´s apache conf file (named /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/manual.domain.com):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin dsanabria@domain.com
    ServerName manual.domain.com

    DocumentRoot "/home/ubuntu/manual/"

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/manual/>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/manual.domain-error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel debug

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/manual.domain-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

And the django app (named /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www.domain.co):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin diego@diegue.us
    ServerName domain.co
    ServerAlias machete.anotherdomain.com
    Alias /admin/media/ /home/ubuntu/webapps/machete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grappelli/media/
    Alias /media/ /home/ubuntu/webapps/machete/machete/media/
    Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/webapps/machete/machete/collected/

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/webapps/machete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grappelli/media/>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/webapps/machete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/ >
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/webapps/machete/machete/media/>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/webapps/machete/machete/collected/>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptReloading On
    WSGIDaemonProcess machete python-path=/home/ubuntu/webapps/machete/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup machete
    WSGIApplicationGroup machete
    WSGIPassAuthorization On

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/webapps/machete/machete/machete/wsgi.py
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/machete-error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel debug

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/machete-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

The first, tells to apache, that if the user gets to manual.domain.com, just response with a php application (joomla). The second file says to apache, that if the user calls the server with www.domain.com response with a python wsgy, (django).

This is in a ubuntu server, redhat/centos/fedora locates the folder sites-enabled in another location that I can´t remember, but anyway you can use virtualhosts.

Generraly, I avoid to mess with the httpd.conf file and prefer use virtualhosts.

Comment: Thanks a lot @diegueus9, this pointed me in the right direction. I'm deploying to a linux server on amazon ec2. I added the file with the virtualhost configuration conf.d at etc/httpd/conf.d . When I restart apache, I get a warning `[warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts` . Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: Actually, It was because I repeated the NameVirtualHost *:80 line and I only needed to include it once.

Comment: @edu222 I need to run both php and python in same ec2 instance. Can you describe about it ?